# how the set the text area always scroll down

Tags: javascript, html

how the set the text area always scroll down  . its default the scroll bar is up .

I am trying to ever 2 min i am reloading the text area evert 2  mins .

the scroll bar is not showing in down .

I want to show scroll bar in down ?

How to achieve in simple way , rather using some other horrible technique ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
myArea.scrollTop = myArea.scrollHeight;
```